# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I have installed a clean version of MacOs and also a new versione of MacTex. While compiling a tex file, i get the following error

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Œ≥ (U+3B3)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

If I compile the same file on the old version of MacOs I don't get this error. Is there any setting of the package inputenc should I change?

It is an error arising from the bibliography file `.bbl`

Comment: U+03B3 is GREEK SMALL LETTER GAMMA. Maybe you can find the problematic entry with that information. You could also try `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B3}{XXXX Here I am XXX}` and search for `XXX` in the output.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand why the compilation works in the old version of MacOs and not in the new clean installation of the operating system.

Comment: In April 2018 LaTeX made UTF-8 the default encoding for `.tex` documents (https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf). Earlier LaTeX would essentially assume ASCII input and characters not in ASCII range would not be handled as expected. The new default handles UTF-8 chars as expected, but not all characters have been set up for use. Previously the gamma would not have errored, but I would be surprised if the output had been as expected.

Comment: What input encoding are you using? What is the encoding of your .bib file?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error from a reference in a bib file. I left the bib file as is and  used `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B3}{$\gamma$}` and it worked a treat. Now the `$\gamma$` comes up nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved this.  Your options include:

- Load the `unicode-math` package in a native Unicode engine, such as LuaLaTeX.  It will understand all Unicode characters.  This is what I would recommend, unless your publisher or professor requires you to use legacy 8-bit fonts.
- Load `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}` on a modern distribution, and it should understand γ in text mode.   it might also need `\usepackage{textgreek}`.  The kernel will only set up the Unicode characters that are in a text encoding that you loaded.
- Do a search-and-replace in your source file.
- Recent versions of `babel` should be able to automatically switch to a Greek font when they see Greek letters.
- Define a command to display γ (either with `inputenc` or `newunicodechar`). This should probably be something like `\ifmmode\gamma\else\textgamma\fi` so it will work in either text or math mode.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @UlrikeFischer!